# i need some gpg encrypt decrypt lib in cpp

Tags: c++, gnupg

Is there any opensource lib in cpp that can encrypt decrypt using private/ public key way?
I just want the encrypt decrypt function, so the few dependance is better. 
I do not need any other function than this. like show system private keys or etc,

It must system independent,

Thanks,

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, there are such open source libraries.

For your research, you could either use your favourite search engine, e.g. http://duckduckgo.com, and look at Open Source hosters like for example http://sourceforge.net, http://github.com or http://gitorious.org.

If you are using a Linux Distribution, you may also have luck in your preferred software manager, like Synaptic or YaST.

Comment: thanks, I found the RSA lib[link](http://code.google.com/p/rsa/)